# $S$-semipermutable subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

A subgroup $H$ of a finite group $G$ is said to be
$S$-semipermutable in $G$ if it permutes with every Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G$ for all primes $q$ not dividing $|H|$.

Assume that $G$ is solvable and let $\{P_{1}, P_{2}, \ldots , P_{s}\}$ be a Sylow basis of $G$. $P^{*}$ is a maximal subgroup of $P_{s}$.
If $P^{*}$ is $S$-semipermutable in $P_{i}P_{s}$ $(i=1, \ldots , s-1) $, then $P^{*}$ is $S$-semipermutable  in $G=P_{1}P_{2}\cdots P_{s}$. (Is this correct?)

$H$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$. $P$ is a Sylow $p$-
subgroup of $G$ with $p$ not dividing $|H|$. If $HP=PH$, can we conclude that $HP^g=P^gH$ for each $g\in G$?

Comment: Cross-posted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422713)